# Append 2 or more choices SAPI

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, sapi

Right now, say I have created a Grammar which have the following elements in it

have, nice, day, they

What I'm trying to do here is, when I say "have", the result of the recognition is "have". When I say "have nice", the result will be "have nice".

How can I append these 2 choices or more into a single result of recognition?

And also, is it possible to add my own words to the DictationGrammar?

Comment: Seeing some code would make this question a lot more clear I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - you can build repeated elements using this GrammarBuilder constructor: [`GrammarBuilder (GrammarBuilder, Int32, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms554231%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Second, you can add words to the dictation grammar using [Lexicons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Unfortunately, the lexicon interfaces in SAPI are not exposed via System.Speech.Recognition, so your choices are either to use C++ and native SAPI, or to use Speechlib and [the SAPI automation wrappers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125186%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Alternatively, if you don't need to do this via code, you can use the speech dictionary that's part of Windows Speech Recognition.

Comment: Thanks for the constructor, it works perfectly fine. Just that the program doesn't work when I tried to load a Scrabble dictionary to it. Hey, is there anyway I can contact you? I have so many questions to ask :O

Comment: @Xeon you can reach me via my blog.  If you're building a several thousand word vocabulary, command & control grammars are not going to work well.  You would need a dictation grammar.